# Clearing controls from a FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, user-controls, flowlayoutpanel

I'm trying to remove the controls of the FlowLayoutPanel in the code that is attached below. The problem is that I use a search function in the same frame, so I can't find other objects without clearing it first. I already tried:

```
fPanelUpperMainScreen.Controls.Remove(a);
```

This is my method that I am working on.

```
public void GetArtistLayout()
        {
            ArtistInformation a = new ArtistInformation();
            fPanelUpperMainScreen.Controls.Add(a);
            int valueInt = int.Parse(tBMainScreen_Search.Text);

            a.pictureBox1.ImageLocation = ar.GetArtist(valueInt).artistPic;

            a.lblArtistInformation_ArtistName.Text = ar.GetArtist(valueInt).artistName;

            var reviews = rr.getMatchingReviewsArtist(valueInt);

            foreach (var review in reviews)
            {
                UserControl1 u = new UserControl1();
                u.lblUser.Text = review.username;
                u.lblComment.Text = review.comments;
                u.lblDate.Text = review.date;
                u.lblRating.Text = review.rating.ToString();
                a.fpArtistInformation_Reviews.Controls.Add(u);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You may want to explain your problem a little more. As it is I don't understand it. also: what is ArtistInformation. Is it Winforms? which control contains which others?

Comment: ArtistInformation is a User Control, containing a pictureBox, Label, and another FlowLayoutPanel.

Comment: So you want to remove the one you added in GetArtistLayout? Since you didn't keep a reference (a is only local) you will have to loop over the Controls collection of fPanelUpperMainScreen and try to identify the one you look for. We can't know which you mean, you could check the type, maybe their controls or a Property you set to identify the ArtistInformation instances..

Comment: This piece of code seem to have made it: `fPanelUpperMainScreen.Controls.Clear();` so I guess it's okay?

Comment: If you want to clear them __all__ it is ok.

Comment: Note: Clearing isn't Disposing.